# Dynamic div close in php while loop

Tags: php, while-loop

code i have written below is working fine but at the end of the looping the div is not closed its still opening a loop

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
       <div class="row">
        <?php 
        $recent_projects_sql="SELECT * from recent_projects where service_type='upholstery'";   
        $recent_projects_conn=mysql_query($recent_projects_sql) or die(mysql_error()); 
        $i=0; $split=0;

        while($projects=mysql_fetch_array($recent_projects_conn)) {   
             $i++; 
             ?>
             <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="col-item" style="">
                    <div class="photo-shadow"></div>
                    <div class="photo">
                        <img src="admin/assets/images/uploads/projects/<?php echo $projects['attachment1']; ?>" alt="User one">
                    </div>
                    <div class="info">
                        <div class="name">
                            <?php echo $projects['service_name']; ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="degination">
                            <?php echo $projects['sub_title']; ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="buttons">
                            <a class="btn btn-theme ripple-effect" href="#">View More</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php 
            $split++;   
            if ($split % 4 == 0){  
               echo '</div></div><div class="item"><div class="row">';  
            }   
       }
       ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Div has splited very well but in end of the loop div has not been closed. Thats only the problem please provide me the help to sort out the problem

When I inspect the element the last loop will show at the given result as follows:

```
                                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                                            <div class="col-item">
                                                <div class="photo-shadow"></div>
                                                <div class="photo">
                                                    <img src="admin/assets/images/uploads/projects/1557301934.jpg" alt="User one">
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="info">
                                                    <div class="name">UPHOLSTERY</div>
                                                    <div class="degination">UPHOLSTERY</div>
                                                    <div class="buttons">
                                                        <a class="btn btn-theme ripple-effect" href="#">View More</a>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div> 
                                        </div></div><div class="item"><div class="row">
```

I want to remove the two opening div's as  dynamically. How can i set this to remove opened div's at then end of the looping

Answer (score 0):

Add a Boolean check for the execution of loop, such as `$check = true;`, add this within the loop.

after the loop add this

```
if($check){
 echo " </div></div>";
}
```

That's because at the end of iteration (in case of mod 4 and even without it), you keep 2 divs opened

```
 echo '</div></div><div class="item"><div class="row">';
```

Answer (score 0):

I just took a quick look and it looks like you are not closing the "carousel-inner" div

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="item active">
    <div class="row">
        <?php
        $recent_projects_sql = "SELECT * from recent_projects where service_type='upholstery'";
        $recent_projects_conn = mysql_query( $recent_projects_sql ) or die( mysql_error() );
        $i     = 0;
        $split = 0;
        while ( $projects = mysql_fetch_array( $recent_projects_conn ) ) {
            $i ++;
            ?>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="col-item" style="">
                    <div class="photo-shadow"></div>
                    <div class="photo">
                        <img src="admin/assets/images/uploads/projects/<?php echo $projects['attachment1']; ?>"
                             alt="User one">
                    </div>
                    <div class="info">
                        <div class="name">
                            <?php echo $projects['service_name']; ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="degination">
                            <?php echo $projects['sub_title']; ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="buttons">
                            <a class="btn btn-theme ripple-effect" href="#">View More</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php $split ++;
            if ( $split % 4 == 0 ) {
                echo '</div></div><div class="item"><div class="row">';
            }
        }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seeing mysql_ should burn your eyes out and make you run screaming from the room :) In a less dramatic approach mysql_ is old, bad and deprecated. You should be using mysqli_ or PDO.

Comment: Carosel inner div is closing, code i have given is a part of code